# Zend framework forms and jQuery selectors - how to select by... ID?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, css-selectors, zend-form

So I've got this issue with forms generated by Zend Framework.

As we know Zend is using this format for ID of HTML elements, i.e: `contactDetails[name]`,`contactDetails[email]` etc.

First of all, why Zend is using *invalid* HTML to generate forms? There should be no brackets `[]` inside ids, according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

But the real issue I have is **how to correctly select element by id using jQuery, if we must deal with invalid, Zend generated ids**?

In standard JavaScript this seems to work: `document.getElementById('contactDetails[email]')`.

But in jQuery: `$('#contactDetails[email]')` - this is obviously wrong, as brackets are reserved for attribute selectors.

The easy workaround I found is to wrap native-js-selected object in $() function:
`$(document.getElementById('contactDetails[email]'))`. Using this method I can use all jQuery functions on this object, but this seems like a hacky solution...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the square brackets:

```
$("#contactDetails\\[email\\]");
```

jQuery expects that those enclose attribute filter expressions. Scroll down to the end of this link:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

From the above:

> The full list of characters that need
>   to be escaped: #;&,.+*~':"!^$=>|/

Comment: @rochal - initially I had only put a single backslash. Please copy and paste the above and give it a try.